# MySQL2 returning connection log

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am attempting to get data from my MySQL databse but it returns

```
[
  [ '_events', [Object: null prototype] {} ],
  [ '_eventsCount', 0 ],
  [ '_maxListeners', undefined ],
  [ 'next', [Function: resultsetHeader] ],
  [ 'sql', 'SELECT * FROM dutylogs ORDER BY time DESC;' ],
  [ 'values', undefined ],
  [
    '_queryOptions',
    {
      rowsAsArray: false,
      sql: 'SELECT * FROM dutylogs ORDER BY time DESC;',
      values: undefined
    }
  ],
  [ 'namedPlaceholders', false ],
  [ 'onResult', [Function (anonymous)] ],
  [ 'timeout', undefined ],
  [ 'queryTimeout', null ],
  [ '_fieldCount', 0 ],
  [ '_rowParser', null ],
  [ '_fields', [] ],
  [ '_rows', [] ],
  [ '_receivedFieldsCount', 0 ],
  [ '_resultIndex', 0 ],
  [ '_localStream', null ],
  [ '_unpipeStream', [Function (anonymous)] ],
  [ '_streamFactory', undefined ],
  [
    '_connection',
    Connection {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      config: [ConnectionConfig],
      stream: [Socket],
      _internalId: 0,
      _commands: [Denque],
      _command: [Query],
      _paused: false,
      _paused_packets: [Denque],
      _statements: [LRUCache],
      serverCapabilityFlags: 2181036030,
      authorized: true,
      sequenceId: 1,
      compressedSequenceId: 0,
      threadId: 4009,
      _handshakePacket: [Handshake],
      _fatalError: null,
      _protocolError: null,
      _outOfOrderPackets: [],
      clientEncoding: 'utf8',
      packetParser: [PacketParser],
      serverEncoding: 'utf8',
      connectTimeout: null,
      connectionId: 4009,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  ],
  [
    'options',
    {
      isServer: undefined,
      stream: undefined,
      host: 'REDACTED',
      port: 3306,
      localAddress: undefined,
      socketPath: undefined,
      user: 'REDACTED',
      password: 'REDACTED',
      passwordSha1: undefined,
      database: 'REDACTED',
      connectTimeout: 10000,
      insecureAuth: false,
      supportBigNumbers: false,
      bigNumberStrings: false,
      decimalNumbers: false,
      dateStrings: false,
      debug: undefined,
      trace: true,
      stringifyObjects: false,
      enableKeepAlive: false,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
      timezone: 'local',
      queryFormat: undefined,
      pool: undefined,
      ssl: false,
      multipleStatements: false,
      rowsAsArray: false,
      namedPlaceholders: false,
      nestTables: undefined,
      typeCast: true,
      maxPacketSize: 0,
      charsetNumber: 224,
      compress: false,
      authPlugins: undefined,
      authSwitchHandler: undefined,
      clientFlags: 11203535,
      connectAttributes: undefined,
      maxPreparedStatements: 16000,
      sql: 'SELECT * FROM dutylogs ORDER BY time DESC;',
      values: undefined
    }
  ]
]
```

From just reading that I can tell it is a connection log, but it doesn't help me much as I am really looking for something like below

```
[
  {
    key: 7044,
    name: '~y~Ten~g~Creator~r~[RIP]',
    id: '518334475038359555',
    dept: 'SAHP',
    time: 33,
    lastclockin: '2022/11/25 22:30:06'
  },
  {
    key: 7042,
    name: '~y~Ten~g~Creator~r~[RIP]',
    id: '518334475038359555',
    dept: 'STAFF',
    time: 2,
    lastclockin: '2022/11/25 21:49:30'
  },
  {
    key: 7043,
    name: '~y~Ten~g~Creator~r~[RIP]',
    id: '518334475038359555',
    dept: 'BCSO',
    time: 1,
    lastclockin: '2022/11/25 21:52:58'
  }
]
```

I am using the EJS view engine to render this but I have the code divided into a router, this was mainly to keep my code clean, more jargen to meet stack overflow's requirements!

```
const express = require('express')
const config = require('../config.json')
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const router = express.Router();

let print = console.log

const sql = mysql.createConnection({
   host: config.sql.host,
   user: config.sql.user,
   password: config.sql.pass,
   database: config.sql.database,
   port: config.sql.port
})

sql.connect()

router.get('/:deptName', (req, res) => {
    let dept = req.params.deptName

    // print(Object.entries(getUnits(dept)))

    res.render('index', {
        siteName : dept,
        serverName : config.serverName,
        navEnabled : config.NavEnabled,
        NavBtns : config.NavBtns,
        deptList : config.departments,
        viewDept : true,
        dept : dept,
        units : Object.entries(getUnits(dept))
    })
})


function getUnits (dept) {
    let sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM dutylogs ORDER BY time DESC;`

    let unitGetter = sql.query(sqlQuery, (err, res, field)=>{
        if (err) throw err
        print(res)
        return res
    })


    return unitGetter
}

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by putting this on line 5

```
let units = [];
```

and setting a time-out before I render the index!

```
    setTimeout(()=>{
        res.render('index', {
            siteName : dept,
            serverName : config.serverName,
            navEnabled : config.NavEnabled,
            NavBtns : config.NavBtns,
            deptList : config.departments,
            viewDept : true,
            dept : dept,
            units : units
        })
    }, 10)
```

then afterwards I had changed the function to set the units value to its response

```
function getUnits (dept) {
    let sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM dutylogs WHERE dept="${dept}" ORDER BY time DESC;`

    let unitGetter = sql.query(sqlQuery, (err, res, field)=>{
        if (err) throw err
        units = res
    })
}
```

Edit: Ok, me after a while of coding just realised why this wasn't working, a better way than making this a global variable would be to make sure it returns properly rather than being a twat (like I was)

```
async function getUnits(dept){
   let res = null
   const sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM dutylogs WHERE dept="${dept}" ORDER BY time DESC;`
   
    await sql.query(sqlQuery, (err, resp, field)=>{
        if (err) throw err
        res = resp
    })

    return res
}
```